# Solve the equation $\sqrt{5x^2+4x}-\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}=5\sqrt{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Solve the equation with $x\in R$$$\sqrt{5x^2+4x}-\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}=5\sqrt{x}$$

---

My try: $\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{5x^2+4x}-21-\left(\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}-6\right)-\left(5\sqrt{x}-15\right)=0$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{5x^2+4x-441}{\sqrt{5x^2+4}+21}-\frac{x^2-3x-18-36}{\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}+6}-\frac{25x-225}{5\sqrt{x}+15}=0$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{\left(x-9\right)\left(5x+49\right)}{\sqrt{5x^2+4}+21}-\frac{\left(x-9\right)\left(x+6\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}+6}-\frac{25\left(x-9\right)}{5\sqrt{x}+15}=0$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(x-9\right)\left(\frac{5x+49}{\sqrt{5x^2+4}+21}-\frac{x+6}{\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}+6}-\frac{25}{5\sqrt{x}+15}\right)=0$

$\Rightarrow x=9$ and $\left(\frac{5x+49}{\sqrt{5x^2+4}+21}-\frac{x+6}{\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}+6}-\frac{25}{5\sqrt{x}+15}\right)=0$ i can't solve it. Help me

Comment: How in the world did you happen to think to subtract the numbers $21$, $6$, and $15$ from the three square roots?  I've pulled rabbits out a hat in my day, but this seems more like a kangaroo!

Comment: @BarryCipra I was wondering the same thing...! Neat, though :-).

Answer (score 2):

after squaring and rearranging we get
$$3x^2-12x-9=\sqrt{5x^2+4x}\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}$$
squaring again and factorizing we get
$$(x-9) (4 x+3) \left(x^2-7 x-3\right)=0$$
Can you finish?

Comment: yes, i can but you can solve $\left(\frac{5x+49}{\sqrt{5x^2+4}+21}-\frac{x+6}{\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}+6}-\frac{25}{5\sqrt{x}+15}\right)=0$ ?

Comment: why this? this is addtionally compligated

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your approach will allow you to easily find the second solution.

Alternatively, square both sides of:
$$\sqrt{5x^2+4x}-\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}=5\sqrt{x}$$
To get:
$$5x^2+4x+x^2-3x-18-2\sqrt{5x^2+4x}\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}=25x$$
Simplifying and rearranging:
$$-2\sqrt{5x^2+4x}\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}=-6 x^2 + 24 x + 18$$
Squaring both sides again:
$$4\left( 5x^2+4x \right)\left(x^2-3x-18\right)=\left(-6 x^2 + 24 x + 18\right)^2$$
Rearranging all to one side and factoring (you already found the root $x=9$):
$$-4 \left(4 x + 3 \right) \left(x - 9 \right) \left(x^2 - 7 x - 3 \right) = 0$$
Note that the squaring may have introduced *extraneous solutions*, so be careful.

Comment: Why the recent downvote? I rather receive a comment to know how I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{5x^2 + 4x} - \sqrt{x^2 - 3x - 18} = 5\sqrt{x}$$
then squaring both sides, we get
$$5x^2 + 4 x + (x^2 - 3x - 18) - 2\sqrt{(5x^2 + 4x) (x^2 - 3x - 18)} = 25 x$$
$$6x^2 + x - 18 - 2\sqrt{(5x^2 + 4x) (x^2 - 3x - 18)} = 25 x$$
$$6x^2 - 24 x - 18 = 2\sqrt{(5x^2 + 4x) (x^2 - 3x - 18)}$$
then squaring both sides, we get
$$(6x^2 - 24 x - 18)^2 = 4(5x^2 + 4x) (x^2 - 3x - 18)$$
$$36x^4 - 288x^3 + 360x^2 + 864x + 324 = 20x^4 - 44x^3 - 408x^2 - 288x$$
So that 
$$16x^4 - 244x^3 + 768x^2 + 1152x + 324 = 0$$
Hence
$$4(4x+3)(x-9)(x^2-7x-3) = 0$$
So that the possible values of $x$ are 
$$x = -\frac{3}{4},9,\frac{7+\sqrt{61}}{2}, \frac{7-\sqrt{61}}{2}$$
We have to substitute these values in the main equation to get the acceptable values of $x$ which are 
$$x = 9 ,\frac{7+\sqrt{61}}{2}$$

Comment: just $x=9$ is an equation solution

Comment: @UchihaItachi also the other root satisfies the main equation. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{5x^2 + 4x} - \sqrt{x^2 - 3x - 18} = 5 \sqrt{x}$$

**Restrictions**

---

$\left[ \begin{array}{rcl}
   5x^2 + 4x  &\ge & 0 \\
   x^2 - 3x - 18 &\ge & 0 \\
   x &\ge & 0
\end{array} \right]
\implies
\left[ \begin{array}{rcl}
   x \le -\dfrac 45 &\text{or} &x \ge 0 \\
    x \le -3        &\text{or} &x \ge 6 \\
   & x \ge 0
\end{array} \right]
\implies x \le -3 \; \text{or} \; x \ge 6$

---

Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{5x^2 + 4x} + \sqrt{x^2 - 3x - 18}$.

\begin{align}
   (5x^2 + 4x) - (x^2 - 3x - 18) 
      &= 5 \sqrt{x}(\sqrt{5x^2 + 4x} + \sqrt{x^2 - 3x - 18}) \\
\hline
   5\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{5x^2 + 4x} + \sqrt{x^2 - 3x - 18})
      &= 4x^2 + 7x + 18 \\
   5\sqrt x(\sqrt{5x^2 + 4x} - \sqrt{x^2 - 3x - 18}) &= 25x \\
\hline
   10\sqrt x \sqrt{5x^2 + 4x} &= 4x^2 + 32x + 18 \\
   5x\sqrt{5x + 4} &= 2x^2 + 16x + 9 \\
   125x^3 +100x^2 &= 4x^4 + 64x^3 + 292x^2 + 288x + 81 \\
   4 x^4 - 61 x^3 + 192 x^2 + 288 x + 81 &= 0 \\
   (4 x + 3) (x - 9) (x^2 - 7 x - 3) &= 0
\end{align}

Applying the restrictions, we get

$$x \in \left\{ \dfrac{7 + \sqrt{61}}{2}, 9 \right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{5x^2+4x}-\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}=5\sqrt{x}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{5x^2+4x}=\sqrt{x^2-3x-18}+5\sqrt{x}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 5x^2+4=x^2+22x-18+10\sqrt{x(x-6)(x+3)}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 4x^2-18x+18=10\sqrt{(x+3)(x^2-6x)}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 4(x^2-6x)+6(x+3)-10\sqrt{(x+3)(x^2-6x)}=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  2.(2\sqrt{x^2-6x}-3\sqrt{x+3})(\sqrt{x^2-6x}-\sqrt{x+3})=0$$
You can finish it.